# Laravel multi foreach

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, while-loop

I want to get a multi sub comments.

How can I it don't have to use foreach() { foreach() { } }...

I have three models:

**strony.php** model

```
    class Strony extends Model
{
        public function komenty() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment', 'taxonomies')->withPivot('parent_id');
    }
    public function sub() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment', 'taxonomies', 'parent_id');
    }}
```

**taxonomy.php** model

```
class Taxonomy extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';


    public function tax() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment','taxonomies', 'parent_id', 'comment_id')->withPivot('parent_id');
    }
}
```

**comment.php** model

```
class Comment extends Model
{
public function subcomment() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment', 'taxonomies', 'parent_id');
    }
    }
```

**controller.php**

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($str->komenty as $g) {
$numer = $g->pivot->comment_id;
$child = $g->pivot->parent_id;

if($child == null) {
echo '<li>' . $g->title;

$cmt = Comment::find($numer);

$sub1 = $cmt;

echo '<ul>';
foreach($sub1->subcomment as $sub2) {
    echo '<li>' . $sub2->title . '</li>';

   echo '<ul>';
    foreach($sub2->subcomment as $sub3) {

            echo '<li>' . $sub3->title . '</li>';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($sub3->subcomment as $sub4) {
                echo '<li>' . $sub4->title . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>';

}
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**table**
this is a my table sql
[image]

-comment1

--comment3

---comment2

---comment4

----comment6

--comment5

```html
<ul><li>comment1<ul><li>comment3</li><ul><li>comment2</li><ul></ul><li>comment4</li><ul><li>comment6</li></ul></ul><li>comment5</li><ul></ul></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: Just a quick tip: use english only for coding; good luck.

Comment: I do not know if this is understandable I used google translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't echo HTML code in your controller, use views: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views

Create two views and use recursive inclusion.

`comment.blade.php`:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($comment->subcomment as $subcomment)
        <li>{{ $comment->title }}</li>
        @include('comment', ['comment' => $subcomment])
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

`comments.blade.php`:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($str->komenty as $comment)
        @if(is_null($comment->pivot->parent_id))
            <li>{{ $comment->title }}</li>
            @include('comment', ['comment' => $comment])
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not working. Why don't use echo in my controller ? Thanks.

Comment: It's just for a try. Display empty pages. If delete  @include('pages.comment', ['comment' => $subcomment]) in comment.blade.php display 2x comment1.

Comment: The code wasn't necessarily meant to work without any adjustments. The goal was to show you how recursion is the solution for your problem. You can also do that in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use

```
 foreach($str->komenty as $g) {
$numer = $g->pivot->comment_id;
$child = $g->pivot->parent_id;

if($child == null) {

echo $g->title . '<br>';
$cmt = Comment::find($numer);

$sub2 = $cmt;
$i = 1;
$o = 2;

while($i < 5) {
    $i++;
    $o++;
    if(isset(${'sub'.$i}->subcomment)) {
foreach(${'sub'.$i}->subcomment as ${'sub'.$o}) {
    $num = ${'sub'.$o}->pivot->comment_id;
    echo ${'sub'.$o}->title . '<br>';
}}}}}
```

It's working only last element.

Because this make `foreach(){} foreach(){}`, not `foreach(){ foreach(){} }`